# Cloud function require authentication error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to trigger the cloud functions with a self-signed JWT for a Google-signed ID token. However, it produces the response *Your client does not have permission to the requested URL*. I am sure that that account has "Cloud Functions Invoker" access and I also get the token successfully.

[image: Permissions dialog]

[image: Error message in HTML]

```
import time
import jwt

import json
# import http.client
# payload
private_key =  "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
token_dict = {
    "iss": "het-query-function@smarter-poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    # "aud": "https://europe-central2-smarter-poc.cloudfunctions.net/query_soc_ota_information",
    "exp": time.time()+3600,
    'iat': time.time(),  # 时间戳
    "sub":"het-query-function@smarter-poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
"""payload 中一些固定参数名称的意义, 同时可以在payload中自定义参数"""
# iss  【issuer】发布者的url地址
# sub 【subject】该JWT所面向的用户，用于处理特定应用，不是常用的字段
# aud 【audience】接受者的url地址
# exp 【expiration】 该jwt销毁的时间；unix时间戳
# nbf  【not before】 该jwt的使用时间不能早于该时间；unix时间戳
# iat   【issued at】 该jwt的发布时间；unix 时间戳
# jti    【JWT ID】 该jwt的唯一ID编号

# headers
headers = {
    'alg': "RS256",  # 声明所使用的算法
    'typ': 'JWT'
}



# 调用jwt库,生成json web token
jwt_token = jwt.encode(token_dict,  # payload, 有效载体 
                       private_key,  # 进行加密签名的密钥
                       algorithm="RS256",  # 指明签名算法方式, 默认也是HS256
                       headers=headers  # json web token 数据结构包含两部分, payload(有效载体), headers(标头)
                       ).decode('ascii')  # python3 编码后得到 bytes, 再进行解码(指明解码的格式), 得到一个str

print(jwt_token)

import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.googleapis.com")
# payload = 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjllN2Q5ZTk1YjZkNTdiY2NiZjBhYmM2NzgzYzc2N2RhYjE2MzFjOWIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpYXQiOjE2NDMwMDUwMzAsImV4cCI6MTY0MzAwNTYzMCwic3ViIjoiZ2NwLXN0b3JhZ2VAc21hcnRlci1wb2MuaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJnY3Atc3RvcmFnZUBzbWFydGVyLXBvYy5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL29hdXRoMi92NC90b2tlbiIsInNjb3BlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb20vYXV0aC9jbG91ZC1wbGF0Zm9ybSJ9.eAgCd5JbliFLoggcE9z7Ybhrd0GO3vb3zBW9N48iDe9tGBkQKaFdgAeANutoYLmLuvQM4m4NSavIKFHWYJHiZ6-ioehUvrs0qHZFe2bBkbNYAMQTW73ERr1XjufnZkgK6u1TUTpcX9u2EiJyMHIuku4PBYlhv8aniIsYojVfA_wVcmKhN0dVeBQzixZ_mhJsIZRPKYDPkJKn4H4oOXgy_ymbvKmguZyYLuPGezgycZpKwhFOvQQTbVSuoKikow9v4JIISXlt0fuspFLlsaEVWRx4468GUJ1SNyYThkXARRFxQAWMsgAJ2Z25I38Z3i-owWDnFKJl8KrtjSGG52sa8w'
payload = 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion='+jwt_token

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+jwt_token,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
conn.request("POST", "/oauth2/v4/token", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
jwt = data.decode("utf-8")
print(jwt)
jwt_list = json.loads(jwt)
print(jwt_list['access_token'])
for v in range(len(jwt_list['access_token'])-1,-1,-1):
    # print(jwt_list['access_token'][v])
    if jwt_list['access_token'][v]!='.':
        break
print(jwt_list['access_token'][v])
print("!!!!!!!")
jwt_str = jwt_list['access_token'][0:v+1]
print(jwt_str)
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("europe-central2-smarter-poc.cloudfunctions.net")
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'bearer  '+jwt_str
}
payload = ""
conn.request("GET", "/query_soc_ota_information/?hello=hello", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
re = data.decode("utf-8")
print(re)
```

Comment: Your code is not creating an **OIDC Identity Token**. Your code is creating a signed JWT which can be used only with some services and can be exchanged for an OAuth Access Token (RBAC). Your JWT cannot be used with Google services that authorize by identity (IBAC).

Comment: I refer the instruction (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)  .Could you tell me how to create an OIDC Identity Token.

Answer (score 0):

OK, your code works for me but with several changes.

It would be helpful to include which JWT you're library; I assume [PyJWT](https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/)

You need to include `target_audience`

```py
ALG="RS256"

PROJECT=os.getenv("PROJECT")
REGION=os.getenv("REGION")
ACCOUNT=os.getenv("ACCOUNT")
FUNCTION=os.getenv("FUNCTION")

EMAIL="{account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com".format(
    account=ACCOUNT,
    project=PROJECT,
)

ROOT="{region}-{project}.cloudfunctions.net".format(
    region=REGION,
    project=PROJECT,
)
ENDPOINT="https://{root}/{function}".format(
    root=ROOT,
    function=FUNCTION,
)

token_dict = {
    "target_audience": ENDPOINT,
    "iss": EMAIL,
    "sub": EMAIL,
    "exp": time.time()+3600,
    "iat": time.time(),
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
}
```

> **NOTE** I think `exp` and `iat` should be integers but your code works as-is.

The `.decode("ascii")` appended to `jwt.encode().decode("ascii")` is incorrect.

The `payload` should not be URL-encoded:

```py
payload = "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={jwt}".format(
    jwt=jwt_token,
)
```

The `/oauth2/v4/token` endpoint does **not** return an `access_token` per @john-hanley comment. It returns an `id_token` (as described by Google in the doc you reference).

```py
jwt = data.decode("utf-8")

jwt_list = json.loads(jwt)
id_token=jwt_list["id_token"]

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(ROOT)
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {token}".format(token=id_token),
}
conn.request("GET", "/{function}".format(function=FUNCTION), headers=headers)
```

> **NOTE** No `payload` (null) not `""`

`main.py`:

```py
import http.client
import json
import jwt
import os
import time

ALG="RS256"

# Use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for consistency
CREDENTIALS=os.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")

f=open(CREDENTIALS)
key=json.load(f)

PRIVATE_KEY=key["private_key"]

PROJECT=os.getenv("PROJECT")
REGION=os.getenv("REGION")
ACCOUNT=os.getenv("ACCOUNT")
FUNCTION=os.getenv("FUNCTION")

EMAIL="{account}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com".format(
    account=ACCOUNT,
    project=PROJECT,
)
ROOT="{region}-{project}.cloudfunctions.net".format(
    region=REGION,
    project=PROJECT,
)
ENDPOINT="https://{root}/{function}".format(
    root=ROOT,
    function=FUNCTION,
)

token_dict = {
    "target_audience": ENDPOINT,
    "iss": EMAIL,
    "sub": EMAIL,
    "exp": time.time()+3600,
    "iat": time.time(),
    "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
}
headers = {
    'alg': ALG,
    'typ': 'JWT'
}
jwt_token = jwt.encode(
    token_dict,
    PRIVATE_KEY,
    algorithm=ALG,
    headers=headers,
)

payload = "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={jwt}".format(
    jwt=jwt_token,
)
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {token}".format(
        token=jwt_token,
        ),
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.googleapis.com")
conn.request("POST", "/oauth2/v4/token", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

jwt = data.decode("utf-8")
jwt_list = json.loads(jwt)
id_token=jwt_list["id_token"]

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(ROOT)
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {token}".format(token=id_token),
}
conn.request("GET", "/{function}".format(function=FUNCTION), headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
re = data.decode("utf-8")
print(re)
```